# Importing scipy.integrate in python3.3, numpy 1.7

Tags: python, scipy

I have recently moved to Python3.3 from python3.2. I installed Numpy 1.7.0 and Scipy 0.11.0. I am running all these on Scientific Linux 6.4.
But when I run:

```
from scipy import integrate
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/scipy/integrate/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
      from .quadrature import *
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 5, in <module>
     from scipy.special.orthogonal import p_roots
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 532, in <module>
     from .lambertw import lambertw
   File "lambertw.pyx", line 24, in init scipy.special.lambertw (scipy/special/lambertw.c:1588)
ValueError: level must be >= 0
```

So I installed Scipy 0.12.0c1, but the problem still remains. Could you please help me fix this issue?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Somebody around here *might* be able to help, but it seems to me that if the package won't even import, it's definitely a bug on scipy's part (or at least on the part of whoever packaged scipy).  You might have better luck if you submit a bug report and/or question on their mailing lists.

Comment: I found these two links: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/32072 and http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1739 The comments in the first say that it has been fixed in a package which has worked for them.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this error here with the same versions. I searched for the file lambert.pyx on my system but could only find lambert.py. I found out that the .pyx file is compiled with cython to a .c file and then to a library with a C compiler. Possibly it must be recompiled to work with Python 3.3.

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can "recompile it to work with Python 3.3"? Thanks.

Comment: I have never done this before. In the scipy bug report somebody solved it by recompiling with a newer cython version: "Upgrade to Cython >= 0.17.1 fixes the "level >= 0" issue. Builds and imports now.". The recompilations are usually done by the package maintainers, so write a bug report for your operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that Scipy 0.11.0 is not compatible with Python 3.3.

You need to wait for 0.12.0, or download the release candidate version 0.12.0rc1, or recompile using the Cython fix mentioned in the comments above.

However, this bug **is** fixed in 0.12.0rc1. You most likely made a mistake in installing it --- there is no file called `lambertw.c` in 0.12.0rc1.

Comment: Thank you very much. Since the problem remains in 0.12.0rc1. I will just wait for scipy 0.12.0.

Comment: This is fixed in 0.12.0rc1, you should double check that you didn't make a mistake in installing it.

Comment: After installing scipy 0.12.0rc1 and importing it I checked with scipy.__version__ and 0.12.0rc1 was shown. Maybe because I installed it over scipy 0.11.0, some parts of the old install are still present. Do you know any way I can totally remove the previous install?

Comment: Note that you know for sure that you are using (parts of) Scipy 0.11.0 if the error message mentions `lambertw.c`. If the error message is different, please paste it. I think totally removing the previous version can be done by removing the `scipy*` directories under `site-packages`. This directory is pointed to by doing `python -c 'import scipy; print(scipy.__file__)'`

Comment: I did that, and when I went to re-download the source I noticed that 0.12.0 was out! So I downloaded and installed it and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.